# Visual Studio 2012 ERD (model first)

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I just encountered an issue which I hope has an easy solution

I have modeled dozens of entities and everything looks and feels great. I have one many->many relationship and the junction table as been built behind the scenes just fine.

One issue however is the requirement for 'print order' field to exist in the junction table.

The two tables are:

procedures and sequences -- their relationship is that a procedure can have X number of sequences and sequences should be able to be reused per procedure BUT each procedure may need a sequence at the very top where as others may need the same procedure at any arbitrary offset/location within the procedure.

I can manually add the "offset" field to the junction table but have no idea how that will be accessed with the entity model/LINQ API.

I need to select all sequences of a procedure but order them according to this "offset" value

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get what your saying...

```
Dim query = model.Sequences.Where(Function(o) o.procedureId = procedureId).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Offset).ToList()
```

I may have it backwards:

```
Dim query = model.Procedures.Where(Function(o) o.sequenceId = sequenceId).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Offset).ToList()
```

If I don't have the table fields correct, please place the table layout in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to essentially add a entity to act something like a junction table. Sorry for confusion.